# Creating Serenity BDD skeleton project with Gradle commands

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver, cucumber-jvm, serenity-bdd

We can generate serenity skeleton project using Maven as below:

```
mvn archetype:generate -Dfilter=serenity
```

However, i need to know what is the command for creating similar skeleton serenity project using Gradle. Or it might not be possible? Or i need to create project using maven then i can start using gradle for that. I am using Serenity>cucumber>junit>java. I am currently learning Serenity and i will appreciate your help.

Answer (score 1):

Gradle doesn't have an "archetype" command, but the Maven archetype should generate gradle build scripts.

Comment: Thanks John to reply. I liked your serenity videos and looking forward to implement Serenity in my Project.

Comment: Can you provide a link that documents how Maven archetypes generate Gradle scripts?

Answer (score 0):

David, If you run maven archetype, it will generate Build.gradle which you can modify it to use different jars.

```
mvn archetype:generate -Dfilter=serenity
```

As well you can look into this below:
https://plugins.gradle.org/plugin/com.orctom.archetype